# How to require at least one property in an object in OpenAPI 3.0?

Tags: swagger, openapi

I have this OpenAPI schema:

```yaml
components:
  schemas:
    User:
      type: object
      required:
        - username
        - email
        - description
        - profile_icon
      properties:
        username
          type: string
        email
          type: string
          format: email
        description
          type: string
        profile_icon
          type: string
```

All of properties are required. This is for `PUT /user/profile`.

I will change this to `PATCH /user/profile`.
Users send parameters just they only request to change.
System validates that at least one parameter is required.

How can I describe one of [username, email, description, profile_icon] is required?

Acceptable example requests:

```json
{
  "username": "Will Smith"
}
```

```json
{
  "email": "test@example.com",
  "profile_icon": "aaaaa.png"
}
```

Not acceptable example (error):

```json
{}
```

The `anyOf` annotator is close but it seems to be only for `$ref` schemas, not properties.

https://swagger.io/docs/specification/data-models/oneof-anyof-allof-not/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The easiest way to require at least 1 property in an object is to use `minProperties: 1`.

```yaml
    User:
      type: object
      minProperties: 1   # <--------
      properties:
        username:
          type: string
        ...
```